# Java Properties File to Use / Forward Slash in Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, configuration, key-value

I have a properties file, and I need to use the / forward slash in some of my keys.

e.g.

```
app.module/hdr.key1=value 1
app.module/hdr.key2=value 2
```

I just have no choice but need to do it that way. Please advise is this achievable and how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: @SaifAhmad The escape character in Java properties is a backslash rather than forward-slash. There is no need to escape a forward-slash in a property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of forward slashes will not cause a problem. To understand why, I suggest you read a [critique of the syntax used in Java properties](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/comparison-with-other-technologies.html#htoc50) that I wrote. In essence, what you need to know is the following:

- Leaving aside edge cases (comment lines, blank lines and escape sequences), the syntax of a *name=value* pair permits almost any character (including forward-slashes) in the *name*.
- The `=` can actually be any of the following: (1) `=` (optionally preceded and/or followed by whitespace); (2) `:` (optionally preceded and/or followed by whitespace); or (3) just whitespace. So, yes `name=value` is equivalent to `name:value` and also to `name value`.
- All escape sequences begin with the backslash character. For details of the escape sequences, I suggest you do a Google search for `java.util.Properties` to find online documentation for that class, and look at the long description of the `load(InputStream)` method.

Comment: Thx Ciaran. I will try it out.